# How To Make a Background Image not Stretch in HTML and show as a whole?

Tags: html, image, css

If I make image position to center, size to `contain`, and `no-repeat`, the whole background image is centered and shown entirely but once I make size to `cover`, the background image is clipped, other setup stretches the image.  Question is how do you show the whole image as background image for any container like div take the size of that container and still show whole image and not stretch?

Comment: Are you sure that the image you want to use is of the same resolution as your screen? For example you can't fit a 2000x2000 image inside a 2000x1000 div because the image would be 1000px bigger than the div which means you either squash the image or you lose 500px on either side (1000px in total but its centered)

Comment: Your logic is flawed. You can't do two things at the same time. Keep the ratio of the image ( show whole image ) and also cover the container ( if the image doesn't have the same proportions as the div ) . For example a portrait image like 200x300 ( 200 width 300 height ) will never cover AND keep it's proportions ( without clipping ) in a landscape div with 300x200

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been discussed quite often on Stackoverflow. What you describe would be done by setting `background-size: 100% 100%;`, but most likely this will distort the width/height proportion of your image, which will make it look bad, which you probaly don't want.

The next solution would be `background-size: 100% 100%;` and `background-position: left top`;. This will typically either cut off part of the image at the bottom or cause some white space at the bottom.

So if you consider all options, there is no real solution for your question - just `background-size: contain` and `background-size: cover`, which you already tried, and the two options I listed. You have to decide on one of them, or you simply use an `img` tag which contains the image and has `width: 100%; height: auto;`, but in this case the height will depend on the image proportions, and it won't be a background image anymore.

Comment: It appears that the solution is to make media queries for each breakpoints and use a different size for the same image or other word multiple images.

Comment: that won't change anything, because the proportion between width and height of the image is always the same no matter how you scale/zoom it

Comment: Sorry I mean create multiple copies of the same image having different sizes (width and height) for each breakpoint to use.  Not sure if this is a practical solution.

Comment: Yes, I know what you meant. But no matter if you use a smaller or larger version of your image, the proportion between its width and height will always remain the same. So for the isue you are describing the size makes no difference, it's all about the width/height proportion.

Comment: ok maybe last comment because I need your advise, is my proposed solution a good workaround.

Comment: Which proposed solution do you mean? You already described both of the usual solutions correctly: `contain` will display the complete image while leaving some whitespace (unless the container element has exactly the proportions of the image), and cover will fill the container element completely, but will likely cut off parts of it (again, unless the container element has exactly the proportions of the image)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a difference between sizes of the image and div, you cannot do that. If the image is larger, just manually crop and resize the image so that it fits the div. If the div is bigger, you need to think about designing it with a different approach or find a higher resolution image. Try to do it with responsive way instead of static though. Hope this basic info helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the real solution is to create media queries for multiple images.